# Locally shift everything by 0.5 to the left in PSTricks

Tags: positioning, pstricks

Is it possible in `PSTricks` to locally shift "everything" by 0.5 to the left? For example, in the MWE below I would like to shift the "y" to the left, so that its new coordinates are `(1.5,2)`. Of course, in this simple example, I could just alter the coordinates directly but if you have whole bunch of objects which you want to translate this is cumbersome.

```
\psset{xunit=1cm,yunit=1cm}
\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(5,5)

\rput(1,1){x}
\begin{<shift to left by 0.5>}
\rput(2,2){y}
\end{<shift to left by 0.5>}
\rput(3,3){z}

\end{pspicture}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Insert the entire content that you want to shift to the left inside `\rput(-0.5,0){...}`.

Perhaps, in a more general setting, use

```
\rput(<h-shift>,<v-shift>){%
  % <stuff>
}
```

to move the content horizontally by `<h-shift>` and vertically by `<v-shift>`.